# I have a problem with a function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my function in javascript, I try to replace automatically the first character when a user types any character, for example.

If the user types the letter a, in the input (with my function) replace that letter with the plus sign (+).

I want to add in my function a condition that allows to **add automatically** the plus sign at the beginning of the input and if is possible **besides mustn't allow to delete** the first character from the input.

*Now my function allows to write only numbers.*

```html
   <div>
      <label>Write a phone number:</label>&nbsp;
      <input type="text" maxlength="12" onkeypress="return number(event)"/>
    </div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">

      function number(e){
        var tecla = e.keyCode;

        if (tecla==8 || tecla==9 || tecla==13){
          return true;
        }
    
        var patron =/[0-9+]/;
  
        var tecla_final = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
        return patron.test(tecla_final);
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Well, right now you don't have a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated, if you want past +44**
Try to this one, and change if you need it

```js
function phoneMask() { 
    num = $(this).val().replace(/\+4{1,2}|\D/g,''); 
    $(this).val("+44" + num); 
}
$("#test").keyup(phoneMask);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <label>Write a phone number:</label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" maxlength="12" id="test"/>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It was just I needed. But, If instead of add the plus sign I want that, the function adds the following value: `+44`. I try to add in this line `$(this).val("+44" + num);` but, instead of adding those lines in the textbox, the input is filled by every time I delete a character. Is there something way to restart the method replace to the default value that I have established. (+44)

Comment: @M4uriXD Updated